# Seemingly random indexes causes out of bounds error when referencing a cell in a table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm not sure if I'm missing something very basic or if this is just another problem I've run into with Swift `UITableview`s. My problem is that I reference a cell in the table view (in this case section 4 row 0) and for some reason swift is giving me an out of bounds error with an index (6) that shouldn't ever exists because the size of the section should only be 4 the log also never showed a 5 (when printing `positionCounter` in the while loop). Any help would be greatly appreciated I have no idea why I would be getting a value of 6 in this instance please let me know if you need me to provide any extra code or clarify anything.

Error Message

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'
```

The code surrounding the error

```
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Item Card", for: indexPath)
            var positionCounter = 0

            while positionCounter < eventSettingsTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 4) {
                print(positionCounter)
                print(String(eventSettingsTableView.numberOfSections) + " NUMBER OF SECTIONS")
                print(String(eventSettingsTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 4)) + " NUMBER OF ROW IN SECTION 4")

                if eventSettingsTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 4)) != nil {
                    print("no")
                } else {
                    print("yes")
                }
                positionCounter = positionCounter + 1
            }
            positionCounter = 0
```

I have narrowed the error down to this line (changing the section from 4 to 3 fixes the error but doesn't explain why `positionCounter` was ever 6)

```
if eventSettingsTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 4)) != nil {
```

**EDIT** - Sorry forgot to mention that this code is located in the `cellForRowAt` function for my `UITableView`

Comment: Could you post the code of your entire viewcontroller?

Comment: @carlos21 the view controller is quite complex and probably too long to post here is there any particular section of the view controller code you need?

Comment: Please post `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSections`

Comment: Is the code shown in `cellForRowAt:`? I wouldn't expect to see a loop in `cellForRowAt:`, neither would I expect to see a hard-coded section number.  If it isn't in `cellForRowAt:` why are you dequeuing cells?

Comment: @Paulw11 this is in the cellForRowAt method and I was planning to use the while loop to check if an item already exists in the section.

Comment: Don't use loops.  Just return the cell requested by `indexPath.row` in `indexPath.section`.  `cellForRowAt:` will be called multiple times for the same indexPath over the lifetime of your table.  You also don't know in what order `cellForRowAt:` will be called.  Similarly with `numberOfRowsInSection`, don't use a loop.  You should have your data in arrays or similar so you can just return the relevant array's `count`.

Comment: Still unsure whats the reason for trying to get the cell which might or might not created? If you want to check if an item there, rather check in dataSource array or numberOfRows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are calling `cellForRowAt:` from within `cellForRowAt:`. This is going to cause issues depending on the situation. You might want to look at implementing the following logic differently:

```
if eventSettingsTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 4)) != nil {
    print("no")
} else {
    print("yes")
}
```

Update:

As @PaulW11 points out, calling the tableview's `cellForRowAt:` from within the data source `cellForRowAt:` should not be an issue. And he's right.

However, I set up a demo project to investigate the issue and removing the call to `cellForRowAt:` but retaining the loop results in the crash not occurring. Additionally, I set up a static array of data and noticed that the crash was not due to a boundary condition either since while the array was 9 items long, I got out of bounds issues indicating that iOS was looking at a 12 item array where the access seemed to be for the 13th item :)

So, at the moment, my suspicion is that this issue is due to some sort of timing/race condition where cellForRowAt: is called multiple times within a loop and something goes wonky. But what that "something" is, I don't know. If somebody has any ideas, I'd be really interested to hear about it since this is an interesting question ...

Comment: Not sure why this would be down voted because this sounds like the probable cause of the issue ill try to take another approach that doesn't infinitely call cellForRowAt.

Comment: I've seen a lot of people do knee-jerk downvotes on SO. I don't think they even read the responses. I've given up trying to figure out why :D But yeah, do let us know what happens when you make that change and if that fixes the issue :)

Comment: Because there are two `cellForRowAt:` functions; one that is part of the datasource protocol and one that is part of the tableview class. In this case the second one is being called from the first one and this is not the problem.

Comment: @Paulw11 If you call `cellForRowAt:` from within `cellForRowAt:`, I believe there would be an issue. For example, if the app is trying to display row 0 and calls `cellForRowAt:` for that, and then the above code executes, isn't that going to cause `cellForRowAt:` on the datasource to fire again?

Comment: No, the tableview `celllForRowAt:` returns the cell that the tableview already has or it returns `nil` if it doesn't have one. Calling the tableview `cellForRowAt:` will not result in a call to the datasource method.  The asker's code *is* a mess, but it is because they haven't set up,their data arrays correctly and don't understand how tableviews are driven.  It seems that they are trying to filter empty items from a section "on the fly", when they should just filter the array once. You are correct that they shouldn't call `cellForRowAt:` in `cellForRowAt:`, but that isn't the cause of crash

Comment: @Paulw11 You are right about the behaviour of `cellForRowAt:` because I just tested it. I was wrong. Thanks for clarifying because it was an opportunity to learn something new. But the funny thing is, that the crash that the OP had does go away if you remove the second call to `cellForRowAt:` - again I am sure because I just tested it. Just trying to figure out why the crash happens at the moment because I find this to be an interesting problem :)

Comment: The crash is because they are using a `while` loop that is unbounded by the size of the array they are working against, and so the logic causes them to run off the end of the array

Comment: @Paulw11 Nope, that's not it. I added constant values (not values returned by calls to delegate methods) and the crash still occurs. I basically am running the loop with the data array counts and the crash still happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139115/discussion-between-paulw11-and-fahim).

Comment: After a bit of work I managed to achieve the result I needed without using cellForRowAt Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: @XvKnightvX Happy to help - but I'm still left scratching my head as to what was happening. But I guess some mysteries take too long to solve :D